# Is there a free Visual studio add-on to generate try/catch blocks from a method that documents exceptions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

Is there a free Visual studio add-on to automatically generate try/catch blocks from a method that documents exceptions ?

Comment: If you're already using ReSharper, then the Agent Johnson plugin is available for free and does what you're looking for.  Unfortunately ReSharper is not free... http://code.google.com/p/agentjohnsonplugin/

Answer (score 1):

Would [CR_ExceptionHelper](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_ExceptionHelper) be what you're after?

It's Open source. Requires either [DXCore](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/) or [CodeRush Xpress](http://devexpress.com/crx) which are both free.

(Update:Erm... also runs Fine on Paid version of CodeRush... But you knew that right :))

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, it's not working..at all for me 8-(. Either the pop-up dialog does not appear (mostly on proprietary assemblies) or no code is generated after clicking OK.